# how to solve this[warning: ignoring file, file was built for unsupported file format]

Tags: c

I got some sample code which is used to do a recursive listing of all files and directories in a FAT12 disk image file from my lecturer.

I follow the instructions carefully but get some strange error msg like this:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file floppy.img, file was built for unsupported file format
(0xEB 0x3C 0x90 0x42 0x53 0x44 0x20 0x20 0x34 0x2E 0x34 0x00 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 ) 
which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): floppy.img
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_check_bootsector", referenced from:
       _main in dos_ls-LKA1e2.o
  "_cluster_to_addr", referenced from:
       _follow_dir in dos_ls-LKA1e2.o
  "_get_fat_entry", referenced from:
  _     follow_dir in dos_ls-LKA1e2.o
  "_mmap_file", referenced from:
        _main in dos_ls-LKA1e2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**gcc ./dos_ls.c floppy.img**  is the command I use in terminal.
dos_ls.c is the c file, floppy.img is the sample img he gave us.

I believe something wrong with ths format of this img?
Could anyone explain this error and tell me how to fix it please?

Update: **For example “./dos_ls floppy.img” would list all the files and directories in the disk image file called floppy.img.** this is the instruction i am given. anything wrong with what I am doing?

**gcc ./dos_ls.c** gives this error msg:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_check_bootsector", referenced from:
      _main in dos_ls-xHY6F1.o
  "_cluster_to_addr", referenced from:
      _follow_dir in dos_ls-xHY6F1.o
  "_get_fat_entry", referenced from:
      _follow_dir in dos_ls-xHY6F1.o
  "_mmap_file", referenced from:
      _main in dos_ls-xHY6F1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**gcc --version**

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-
include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Update:
**gcc -o hello dos_ls.c dos.c** create a new file in current directory:

```
Usage: dos_ls <imagename>
logout

[Process completed]
```

What is the correct way to execute this...??

Comment: why on earth are you trying to compile a `.img` file?!

Comment: The undefined symbols are apparently functions that are called in the dos_ls.c file but not defined in that file. Maybe your lecturer gave you a library to link with, or a couple of .h/.c files to compile along with dos_ls.c ?

Comment: @SirDarius yes, with couple of .h/.c files all in current directory and used #include" " to link with.

Comment: the lazy solution... `gcc -o dos_ls *.c`

Comment: @SirDarius Sorry, but what does it mean?

Comment: compile every .c file in the current directory and create an executable file named dos_ls. This is not a real solution, though, see my answer instead ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you have added to the question, your problem is that the `dos_ls.c` file calls a few functions that are not defined there.
Therefore, the linker complains that no implementation has been found for these functions, so the symbols are undefined.

If your lecturer provided you with more .c source files containing the definition for these functions (and the associated header files providing the function declarations) you have to compile them along with your main source files.

I'm assuming fat12 related functionality, so I'm imagining you have the following files:

```
dos_ls.c
fat12.h
fat12.c
```

Normally, dos_ls.c will `#include "fat12.h"`, and you need to compile the .c file using a command line like this:

```
gcc -o dos_ls dos_ls.c fat12.c
```

This should work.

Now, to execute the binary using the provided image file as an argument, just type:

```
./dos_ls floppy.img
```

This is exactly the instruction you quoted in your question.

Comment: This works. I paste the result here, would you mind having a look at the question again :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to compile this code and then execute it?
At a guess, perhaps you should compile first

> gcc ./dos_ls.c

which generates executable code you can then run.

for example if the gcc creates an executable named a.out which runs code that takes a image file as an argument :

> ./a.out floppy.img

Comment: I believe that would be `./a.out floppy.img`, since the current directory is not typically part of `$PATH`

Comment: @Seamus the instruction given by lecturer is “./dos_ls floppy.img” would list all the files and directories in the disk image file called floppy.img" and I've tried what you said, same error msg only without the first part about the format.

Comment: Try running "gcc --version" without quotes to see what the target archicture is. Paste the result in your question